# Jumbox server connection

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have follow situation. I connect on a jumpbox server with my account domain\username and password from my computer. On jumpbox server I connect from SQL Server Management Studio on others servers, where I have databases, using Windows Authentication.

I want to write a Windows application on my computer that connect to databases but I receive this error: "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"

I put my domain on Window Credential and on application I use this string to

```
connect: connetionString="Server=myServerDatabase ; 
Database= myDatabase; Integrated Security=SSPI; User 
ID=myDomain/username;Password=MyPass"
```

If you have others idea how to connect or if it's possible to pass from jumpbox server and then connect to database server and then to database.

Comment: Are you database server publicily accessible or you have to use jumpbox server always?

Comment: Put some information regarding jumpbox as well

Comment: I always I have to use jumpbox to connect to database. Jumpbox is a server and I connect to it using a domain and when I connect to it I use domain\username